# Is there a source for fizzbin?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, history-of

In [*A Piece of the Action*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Piece_of_the_Action_(Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series)), Kirk invents a card game known as Fizzbin that he uses to catch the interest of their guards so they can catch them off-guard and subue them:

In 1950, a similar gag was used in [*The George Burns and Gracie Allen Show*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_George_Burns_and_Gracie_Allen_Show).  Burns invents a game named kleebob to confuse his wife (you can skip the first 74 seconds or so of this clip):

While the rules for fizzbin and kleebob are quite different, the gag or idea is the same: Invent a card game that will confuse someone else so you can trick them.

After posting [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61395/688) on a sister SE site, asking if there is a source for the kleebob gag, it also makes me wonder if the kleebob scene was the source or inspiration for the fizzbin scene in *Star Trek*.

Is there any evidence that David Harmon or Gene Coon were familiar with this scene or if this is their inspiration for fizzbin?

Comment: Over thousands of hours of television, it's hardly surprising that there are two scenes of made-up card games devised to trick someone. It doesn't mean that there was an inspiration.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon: It also doesn't mean there wasn't - which is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 4):

**Possible**

It seems to have been improvised on the spot, but it is possible that the actors were familiar

From the director:

> Komack said, "Like most good comedy, a good deal of the episode was
>   improvised, particularly the Fizzbin card game played by Capt. Kirk
>   and a group of dim-witted gangsters. They just sat down and did
>   it...Shatner really thought of this idea, and I embellished it"

-- These are the Voyages Volume 2, Marc Cushman

Obligatory TV Tropes: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CalvinBall

It appears there were other instances of this sort of thing occurring prior to the Star Trek episode. Specifically tangential to Star Trek is that a similar situation happened in an episode of 'I Love Lucy'. 'I Love Lucy' of course was produced by Desilu, the same studio that initially owned Star Trek (although by Season 2 it was already in the process of being sold to Paramount)

TL;DR - seems to have been a not uncommon trope already so it's certainly likely that on some level the cast / crew were familiar with this kind of comedy bit.

Comment: Then is there any indication that the actors were aware of kleebob or that Shatner had seen the scene.